# How to send AppleID to the Sign in field using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, webdriverwait, nosuchelementexception

Why is this incorrect:

Web page: https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/signin?appIdKey=a01459d797984726ee0914a7097e53fad42b70e1f08d09294d14523a1d4f61e1&rv=2&path=

Steps followed:

1. Inspect, element selector, click on Apple ID field box
2. shows:

```
<input type="text" class="force-ltr form-textbox form-textbox-text" id="account_name_text_field" can-field="accountName" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-required="true" required="required" aria-describedby="apple_id_field_label" spellcheck="false" ($focus)="appleIdFocusHandler()" ($keyup)="appleIdKeyupHandler()" ($blur)="appleIdBlurHandler()" placeholder="Apple&nbsp;ID" autofocus="">
```

3. My code:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("account_name_text_field").send_keys(username)
```

4. Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="account_name_text_field"]"}
```

I've even put sleep for 100 sec just in case it was erroring because of it was taking a while to load.

Comment: Have you verified that the element was actually found by your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pat yourself on the back as there are a lot of positive take away, as you have identified the desired element just perfect. However, the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so to invoke `click()` on the desired element you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    driver.get("https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/signin?appIdKey=a01459d797984726ee0914a7097e53fad42b70e1f08d09294d14523a1d4f61e1&rv=2&path")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"aid-auth-widget-iFrame")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "account_name_text_field"))).send_keys("Tom")
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: AppleID]

---

### Reference

Here you can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Comment: Done, thanks again! Ive come across a similar issue where I cant select the drop down menu through the id or the "web driver wait approach" you showed me. Its probably because its in the actual interface so isn't a "static"  drop-down list. I assume you'll need to see the code on the page but thought; there might already be a thread you can point me to, or to at least make you aware of it first as you're clearly highly experienced and knowledgeable.

Comment: @Tom Can you raise a new question as per new requirement?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60382307/navigating-and-scraping-web-interfaces-with-python/60382355#60382355